# How to change color of title of RadioListTile widget on selection?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have two RadioListTiles on a screen in a row widget, I want to change color of title's text 'Radio 1' on selection of RadioListTile into red color and other RadioListTile which is unselected, and change that unselected RadioListTile's title's color in black.

Any idea would be appreciated

```
          Row(
            children: [
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: RadioListTile(
                  value: 1,
                  groupValue: selectedRadioTile,
                  title: Text('Radio 1'),
                  onChanged: (int value) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedRadioTile = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: RadioListTile(
                  value: 2,
                  groupValue: selectedRadioTile,
                  title: Text('Radio 2'),
                  onChanged: (int value) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedRadioTile = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

use style parameter in Text Widget for Styling the Text

```
title: Text('Radio 1',style: TextStyle(color: selectedRadioColor),),
```

Comment: I have tow RadioListTile on a screen, when one RadioListTile is selected then title's text change to red color and other RadioListTile which is un selected, that  title's text change to black color.

Answer (score 0):

```
    RadioListTile(
                  value: 1,
                  groupValue: selectedRadioTile,
                  title: Text('Radio 1', 
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          textScaleFactor: 2.0,
                          style: TextStyle(  
                             fontSize: 35,  
                             color: Colors.purple,  
                             fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,  
                             fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,  
                             letterSpacing: 8,  
                             wordSpacing: 20,  
                             backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,  
                             shadows: [  
                             Shadow(color: Colors.blueAccent, offset: Offset(2,1),blurRadius:10)  
                             ]  
                            ),  
                           ),
          activeColor: selectedRadioColor,
          onChanged: (int value) {
          setState(() {
          selectedRadioTile = value;
          },
         );
        },
     )
```

I hope It answers everything..